# How organize this function to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I'm working on extending the date filter in my plugin [Ideal Forms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) to allow the user to configure the date format, i.e. `dd/mm/yyyy`, `mm-dd-yyyy`... This is what I got so far:

```
  date: {
    regex: function (input, value) {
      var

      // Just grabbing some info from the plugin...
      data = input.userOptions.data
        ? input.userOptions.data.date
        : { format: 'mm/dd/yyyy' }, // default format

      separator = '\\' + /[^mdy]/.exec(data.format)[0], // extract separator
      userFormat = data.format.replace(/[^mdy]/g, ''), // convert to proper format

      isDate = function (m, d, y) {
        return m > 0 &&
          m < 13 &&
          y > 0 &&
          y < 32768 &&
          d > 0 &&
          d <= (new Date(y, m, 0)).getDate()
      },

      n2 = '(\\d{1,2})', // day and month
      n4 = '(\\d{4})', // year

      format = {
        'mmddyyyy': function () {
          var re = new RegExp(n2 + separator + n2 + separator + n4),
              m = re.exec(value)
          return m && isDate(m[1], m[2], m[3])
        },
        'ddmmyyyy': function () {
          var re = new RegExp(n2 + separator + n2 + separator + n4),
              m = re.exec(value)
          return m && isDate(m[2], m[1], m[3])
        },
        'yyyymmdd': function () {
          var re = new RegExp(n4 + separator + n2 + separator + n2),
              m = re.exec(value)
          return m && isDate(m[2], m[3], m[1])
        },
        'yyyyddmm': function () {
          var re = new RegExp(n4 + separator + n2 + separator + n2),
              m = re.exec(value)
          return m && isDate(m[3], m[2], m[1])
        }
      }

      return format[userFormat]() || format['mmddyyyy']()
    },
```

When using formats other that the default `mm/dd/yyyy` problems come since the function `isDate` tests the date starting with the month value, so when I pass a custom format like `dd-mm-yyyy`, the call `isDate(m[2], m[1], m[3])` works but it will also validate values like `12-13-1986` but not `13-13-1986`.

How can I begin fixing this? Any ideas?

Comment: What would you expect `13-13-1986` to return? `1-13-1987` or null/false for an invalid date?

Comment: well `13-13-1986` should obviously return `false` and it does, it is not a valid date for this format `dd-mm-yyyy`. Then `1-13-1987` should be `false` too but it returns `true`. If the format is the default `mm/dd/yyyy` then everything works as expected and `1/13/1987` will return false, thus preventing validation.

Comment: It must be the order of evaluation of the `isDate` return value but how to fix it? I'm clueless, been working too long...

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit to my answer, `isDate` is all right: http://jsfiddle.net/nQMYe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I wanted to address your comment regarding the return of `isDate`, too. The function behaves as expected, the problem is elsewhere. I haven't dissected your code enough to say where the bug is, but `isDate` is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/nQMYe/

---

**Original Answer**

I have had good luck with a variation of the snippet here: http://joey.mazzarelli.com/2008/11/25/easy-date-parsing-with-javascript/

Basically, it implements a `fromString` method in the Date object. I don't care for that approach, so I've modified my implementation to standalone as a function, and eliminated some of the unnecessary bits. That said, it works great.

The basic idea is to first normalize the input. Since you never know if the user is giving you a format like `1.11.2011` or `3~12~2012`, first thing is to just strip away that noise:

```
data = data.replace(/[^:a-z0-9]/g, '-');
```

We're discarding all non alpha-numeric chars and dropping in a `-`, you seem to prefer `/` -- whatever, just get the input consistent-ish. We keep the alpha so we can deal with `March 18, 2012` too.

The snippet then parses through the input, extracting time (if give, uses : to identify), then it establishes a year. As pointed out in the comments, the day and month are next to each other in most reasonable formats, so you're looking to establish what is NOT the year and going from there. It is then a process of elimination to determine the month, then the day.

Not my code, so I don't mean to take credit for the idea, but again, the thing delivers as advertised. You can either use it as-is (BSD license), or read through the source and dissect the concept.

Here is the code, for posterity:

```
/**
 * @author Joey Mazzarelli
 * @website http://bitbucket.org/mazzarelli/js-date/
 * @website http://joey.mazzarelli.com/2008/11/25/easy-date-parsing-with-javascript/
 * @copyright Joey Mazzarelli
 * @license BSD license
 */

Date.fromString = (function () {

  var defaults = {
    order : 'MDY',
    strict : false
  };

  var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG",
      "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

  var abs = ["AM", "PM", "AFTERNOON", "MORNING"];

  var mark = function (str, val) {
    var lval = val.toLowerCase();
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + lval + '|(.*[^:alpha:])' + lval, 'g');
    return str.replace(regex, '$1' + val);
  };

  var normalize = function (str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    str = str.replace(/[^:a-z0-9]/g, '-');
    for (var i=0; i<months.length; i++) str = mark(str, months[i]);
    for (var i=0; i<abs.length; i++) str = mark(str, abs[i]);
    str = str.replace(/[a-z]/g, '');
    str = str.replace(/([0-9])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2');
    str = ('-' + str + '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
    return str;
  };

  var find_time = function (norm) {
    var obj = {date:norm, time:''};
    obj.time = norm.replace(
        /^.*-(\d\d?(:\d\d){1,2}(:\d\d\d)?(-(AM|PM))?)-.*$/, '$1');
    if (obj.time == obj.date)
      obj.time = norm.replace(/^.*-(\d\d?-(AM|PM))-.*$/, '$1');
    if (obj.time == obj.date) obj.time = '';
    obj.date = norm.replace(obj.time, '');
    obj.time = ('-' + obj.time + '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
    obj.date = ('-' + obj.date + '-').replace(/-+/g, '-');
    return obj;
  };

  var find_year = function (norm) {
    var year = null;

    // Check for a 4-digit year
    year = norm.replace(/^.*-(\d\d\d\d)-.*$/, '$1');
    if (year != norm) return year; else year = null;

    // Check for a 2-digit year, over 32.
    year = norm.replace(/^.*-((3[2-9])|([4-9][0-9]))-.*$/, '$1');
    if (year != norm) return year; else year = null;

    // Day is always by month, so check for explicit months in 
    // first or third spot
    year = norm.replace(/^.*-[A-Z]{3}-\d\d?-(\d\d?)-.*$/, '$1');
    if (year != norm) return year; else year = null;
    year = norm.replace(/^.*-(\d\d?)-\d\d?-[A-Z]{3}-.*$/, '$1');
    if (year != norm) return year; else year = null;

    // If all else fails, use the setting for the position of the year.
    var pos = '$3';
    if (defaults.opts.order.charAt(0) == 'Y') pos = '$1';
    else if (defaults.opts.order.charAt(1) == 'Y') pos = '$2';
    year = norm.replace(/^.*-(\d\d?)-([A-Z]{3}|\d{1,2})-(\d\d?)-.*$/, pos);
    if (year != norm) return year; else year = null;

    return year;
  };

  var find_month = function (norm, year) {
    // Check for an explicity month
    var matches = norm.match(/[A-Z]{3}/);
    if (matches && matches.length) return matches[0];

    // Remove the year, and unless obviously wrong, use order
    // to chose which one to use for month.
    var parts = norm.replace(year + '-', '').split('-');
    if (parts.length != 4) return null;
    var order = defaults.opts.order;
    var md = order.indexOf('M') < order.indexOf('D')? 1: 2;
    return (parseInt(parts[md], 10) <= 12)? parts[md]: parts[md==1? 2: 1];
  };

  var find_day  = function (norm, year, month) {
    return norm.replace(year, '').replace(month, '').replace(/-/g, '');
  };

  var create_absolute = function (obj) {

    var time = obj.time.replace(/[-APM]/g, '');
    var parts = time.split(':');
    parts[1] = parts[1] || 0;
    parts[2] = parts[2] || 0;
    parts[3] = parts[3] || 0;
    var ihr = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    if (obj.time.match(/-AM-/) && ihr == 12) parts[0] = 0;
    else if (obj.time.match(/-PM-/) && ihr < 12) parts[0] = ihr + 12;
    parts[0] = ("0" + parts[0]).substring(("0" + parts[0]).length - 2);
    parts[1] = ("0" + parts[1]).substring(("0" + parts[1]).length - 2);
    parts[2] = ("0" + parts[2]).substring(("0" + parts[2]).length - 2);
    time = parts[0] + ":" + parts[1] + ":" + parts[2];
    var millisecs = parts[3];

    var strict = defaults.opts.strict;
    if (!obj.year && !strict) obj.year = (new Date()).getFullYear();
    var year = parseInt(obj.year, 10);
    if (year < 100) {
      year += (year<70? 2000: 1900);
    }

    if (!obj.month && !strict) obj.month = (new Date()).getMonth() + 1;
    var month = String(obj.month);
    if (month.match(/[A-Z]{3}/)) {
      month = "JAN-FEB-MAR-APR-MAY-JUN-JUL-AUG-SEP-OCT-NOV-DEC-"
          .indexOf(month) / 4 + 1;
    }
    month = ("0" + month).substring(("0" + month).length - 2);
    if (!obj.day && !strict) obj.day = (new Date()).getDate();
    var day = ("0" + obj.day).substring(("0" + obj.day).length - 2);

    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(Date.parse(year + '/' + month + '/' + day + ' ' + time));
    date.setMilliseconds(millisecs);
    return date;
  };

  var parse = function (norm) {
    return absolute(norm);
  };

  var absolute = function (norm) {
    var obj = find_time(norm);
    obj.norm = norm;
    obj.year = find_year(obj.date);
    obj.month = find_month(obj.date, obj.year);
    obj.day = find_day(obj.date, obj.year, obj.month);
    return create_absolute(obj);
  };

  return function (fuzz, opts) {
    defaults.opts = { order: defaults.order, strict: defaults.strict };
    if (opts && opts.order) defaults.opts.order = opts.order;
    if (opts && opts.strict != undefined) defaults.opts.strict = opts.strict;
    var date = parse(normalize(fuzz));
    return date;
  };

})();
```

Comment: You're right my problem must be somewhere else. I just tried isolating my code here http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/nQMYe/4/ and it does indeed work. I'll accept your answer anyway. Thx.

Comment: If you get frustrated, or just want a break, do try the snippet I posted. It is able to be dropped in as-is to test it out, anyway, and seems pretty solid from my own use of it. Users have been especially impressed with the ability to use php-esq strtotime strings instead of having to be careful of a format.

Comment: I'm trying your code but I dont quite get how to use it to return `true` or `false` given a date...

Comment: Joey Mazzarelli's code, and it doesn't return true or false. You pass it a string, it moves mountains to turn that string into a date object, which it hands back. If you simply copy/paste that code as-is, you would use `var date_obj = Date.fromString(user_string_here);`

Comment: I kept testing and it seems to also spit timestaps for random values like `"AsDfgasdf"` I guess my question is how to validate the timestap?

Comment: Ya... it does indeed always return a date, no matter what you send it. That's desirable in my use case, but maybe not in yours. I included that to give you some ideas... as you said, your code IS working, the problem seems to be caused by other factors.

Comment: I fixed it! I developed my own thing after all. It does work as expected and the code is shorter than I expected, so that's good. http://pastebin.com/930VswWJ. It allows any format as param in this fashion: `dd~mm~yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy-dd-mm`. Basically anything with 4 digit year and any delimiter.